# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'newsticker'

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've done a search, and I've found a few results, but none that seem to work - hoping someone can help me or point me in the right direction.
I have a web page with jQuery loaded and a 3rd party script, News Ticker. I have an existing site with this working fine with no problems, however, when I copy the code to another side, I keep getting:
`Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'newsticker'`

The code causing this error is the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#guestbook").newsticker();
});
```

The News Ticker script details can be seen at their site - http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/newsticker/.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Arey you sure you don't have any other js error?

Comment: Yes, that's the only error showing up in the javascript console

Comment: Yes. I used the code below to double check this, and the alert "guestbook doesn't exist" does not show

Answer (score 0):

Because newsTicker **has a capital T**

```
$("#guestbook").newsTicker();
```

You have to be wary that JS is case sensitive in it's syntax.

Comment: +1 What programming language in modern use isn't case sensitive in it's syntax?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference - I've tried both. But thanks anyway

Comment: @Parker1090 did you load jQuery first, the newsTicker next, then your script?

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Yes - in that order. I have checked the files using Chrome's network tab (under inspect element) to ensure all files have loaded fully too

Answer (score 0):

That element may not exist. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    alert("jQuery loaded!");

    if($("#guestbook").length == 0)
        alert("#guestbook doesn't exist");
    else if(!('newsTicker' in $("#guestbook")))
        alert("newsTicker not loaded");
    else
        $("#guestbook").newsTicker();
});
```

Comment: I get the alert box stating that jQuery has loaded, but no further alerts, just the error

Comment: @Parker1090 Updated try that.

Comment: jQuery loaded, newsTicker not loaded... but the file exists, copied straight from another working site I have worked on

Comment: I can't vouch for a plugin 5 years since being updated. You may want to create a new question in which you explain what you want to happen and your attempts thus far.